# Better way to handle inheritance in constructors

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor

I have the following BaseClass

```
class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
    def __init__(self, val1, val2):
        self.v1 = val1
        self.v2 = val2
```

and then some extended class:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(self.__class, self).__init(*args[:len(args)-1], **kwargs
        self.v3 = args[len(args)]
```

basically i want to call it in a way such that:

x = B(1, 2, 34)

but this seems that i need to have a specific order, how do implement **init** the right way so that the base class can initialize its v1,v2 variables and the extended class B can initialize the v3 value (in this case with 34).

Comment: What are you asking? If the syntax was correct (`super(B, self).__init__(*args[:-1], **kwargs)` and `self.v3 = args[-1]`) it would work.

Comment: It seems like a bad idea to pass `self.__class` to `super`.  Why not just pass `B`?

Comment: Also, do you intend to have multiple inheritance at any point?  if yes, having the overriding method with a different signature than the base class could get really tricky.

Comment: Passing `self.__class__` to super is wrong.  You need to pass `B`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be explicit about the required arguments for the super class `A.__init__`. If you provide < 2 args to `B` then you would get an error.

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, val1, val2, *args):
        super(self.__class, self).__init__(val1, val2)
        self.v3 = args  # or args.pop() or whatever
```